# Error while running Agora video on production server, works locally

Tags: authentication, video, angular6, agora.io

I am trying to create a video chat using Angular 6 and Agora Web v2.50 SDK. I followed the tutorial on this link,
https://medium.com/@Anderson7301/building-a-video-chat-app-with-agora-and-angular-6-858d72b6fa0d
I was able to successfully implement this on my local machine but when I try to run it on the server I am getting “main.c71419ff14e542f66f51.js:1 ERROR TypeError: o.default.debug is not a function”.
Can you please help me with. The server is running on SSL.

Update - 11/20/2018

I figured out that I needed to use the Dynamic Key for making the video chat work on the server. So I used the Dynamickey Generation Java code and created the token and while trying to join the user I am getting "Agora-SDK [ERROR]: User join failed [ERR_NO_AUTHORIZED]". Here's the log from my angular application.

11:24:34:202 Agora-SDK [INFO]: Creating client , MODE : interop CODEC : vp8
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:34:215 Agora-SDK [INFO]: Initializing AgoraRTC client, appId: 1d82f0b2b87d445d81dfb2caf4f5e5b9.
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:34:264 Agora-SDK [INFO]: Initializing AgoraRTC client, appId: 1d82f0b2b87d445d81dfb2caf4f5e5b9.

active.component.ts:649 AgoraRTC client initialized
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:34:272 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Connect to choose_server: https://ap-web-1.agora.io/api/v1
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:34:282 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Connect to choose_server: https://ap-web-2.agoraio.cn/api/v1
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:34:951 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Get gateway address: (3) ["webrtc-159-117-159-4.agora.io:5875", "webrtc-128-1-33-131.agora.io:5866", "webrtc-159-117-159-3.agora.io:5870"]
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:34:957 Agora-SDK [INFO]: Joining channel: 1000
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2 11:24:34:964 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: register client Channel 1000 Uid 1587154302
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:34:973 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: start connect:webrtc-159-117-159-4.agora.io:5875
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:35:131 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: websockect opened: webrtc-159-117-159-4.agora.io:5875
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:35:235 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: Connected to gateway server
AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:2

11:24:39:336 Agora-SDK [ERROR]: User join failed [ERR_NO_AUTHORIZED]

The Dynamic token generated is **005AQAoAEY5MDBDNERFRkMxNzdDMkJGRjc5QUY5NDY2QTVEMDYzRTY4QTJCMDEQAB2C8LK4fURdgd+yyvT15bmaofNbWm6O7wAAAAAAAA==**

AppId for my Project is **1d82f0b2b87d445d81dfb2caf4f5e5b9**

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Helpful may be ["how to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Users here are way more ready to help if you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some input and the desired output.

Comment: Please give us a more detailed reproduction on this issue, like does it work without SSL? Does it work in development environment on the  server?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with
`TypeError: o.default.debug` when running in an Angular production build. It looks like the Agora library does not play well with the JS minifier which is used by Angular CLI in production builds.
The only workaround I've come up so far is to set

`"optimization": false`

in angular.json, but that for sure is a very bad workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having looks related to the user auth. Does the project work if you disable the token?

When you make the request to the token server to generate the access token are you passing a UserId? Are you using the same UserId when trying to join the channel or are you using the auto generation?

The reason I ask is because in my own recent testing with Agora.io's Token server, I noticed that you can generate a token with or without a `UserId`.

If you specify the `UserId` in the token generation, you need to reuse that `UserId`. If you pass a `UserId` as part of the request but then try to join the channel with the token and pass `null` as the `UserId` in the join it will fail.

If you don't specify a `UserId` in the token generation *(the token should still generate)* then you can use pass `null` as the `UserId` when joining the channel and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a 10 digit random user id and pass that to the index code and use the same user id to generate the token. You will definitely join the channel

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case i implemented the token server in php with laravel, taked the answer from H Virginia Singh

```
$uid = (int) mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999);
```

And perfect. That definitelly worked for me.